# Embedded YouTube iMovie created in Dreamweaver CS3 not visible when using Internet Explorer

Tags: html

Embedded YouTube iMovie created in Dreamweaver CS3 not visible when using Internet Explorer,but work fine using Safari, FireFox and Chrome.

NEW TO ALL THIS CODE BUSINESS

www.redstonecreative.eu

Here's what the code is like - (THANKS)

//

//

//

Comment: Redirect IE users to the Google Chrome download page. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I'd just grab the embed code from youtube, manually add it to the code for your page, and alter the width and height values accordingly.

Dreamweaver will ultimately cost you more time than it saves when it comes to writing nice code that works predictably.

Get Notepad++ or Aptana, and use something like http://html5boilerplate.com/ as your template for code. You'll have an easier time of it in the long run.